# SNMP4J-2.2.2 & support for SNMP V3

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

My java application uses the snmp4j-2.2.2 jar. I just need to know whether this version will support SNMP V3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `snmp4j-2.2.2` does support SNMPv3. But I would highly recommend using the latest stable version - 2.5.6.